# Problem connecting to localhost: Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/oauth/status from localhost:8009 to http://localhost:8080

Tags: network

Built on mac. Just got localhost working

Same problem as [Playground client can't connect to playground server (all localhost)](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/6323/playground-client-cant-connect-to-playground-server-all-localhost) but the answer is not working for me. I tried the suggestion but its the same problem

The only way I can get the development server working is with `GC_DONT_GC=1 npm start`

I can then visit localhost but in the terminal I see

```
70 WARNINGS in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
webpack compiled with 71 warnings
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled with warnings.
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/oauth/status from localhost:8009 to http://localhost:8080 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.